# Independent models relationship

Tags: python, django

Let's say i have several different models in django project. Now i need to implement reddit-like rating system, that can be easily added to any model in the project. Model look like this:

```
class Rating(models.Model):

    vote = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

The question is - how to connect this 'abstract' model to any other model in project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need generic relations from built-in [contenttypes framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations).

Answer (score 1):

First (and with the disclaimer that I don't know anything about Reddits rating system), unless you want users to put in ratings from negative millions to positive millions, why not use [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices)?

Now to the problem at hand: A model that is rate-able should have a relation that allows many ratings to one model. Unfortunately this means that none of the relationship fields in Django will work. The absolute simplest solution to this is to have the rating in the actual model.

If you don't want to copy-paste the rating fields you can use an abstract model and inherit from that:

```
class RateableModel(models.Model):
    rating      = models.Integerfield(...)
    rating_user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class SomeModelThatCanBeRated(RateableModel):
    # Fields for this model
```